# How to handle drag-and-drop to a Win32 application icon?

Tags: winapi

I have to update a Win32 application in order to handle the drag-and-drop of files over the icon of the executable.
I am not sure about how to proceed. A few researches led me to considering the "WM_DROPFILES" message, but MSDN syas it is "Sent when the user drops a file on the window", while I don't want to open a window.
Think of a command line tool "MyProgram.exe" : if I drag "MyFile.file" on the windows icon "MyProgram" in the desktop, I would like it to execute the same way as it would do when typing ">MyProgram MyFile.file" in the command prompt.

Any idea how to achieve this result ?

Comment: In my experience, dropping a file onto an executable is the equivalent of launching the executable with the filename passed as the first argument. What are the command line arguments when your executable is launched by dropping a file onto it?

Comment: @flashk You are right, it works ! I didn't even tried that. Can you please make your comment an answer so that I can mark the question as closed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does this for you automatically. Any program foo.exe accepts drags of any file.

Martyn

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that apps get this for free by parsing the command line, there is a shell interface called [IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679679.aspx) you can implement if you need more control. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121.aspx#appPaths) and [this blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20100604014706/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/03/10006065.aspx) for more details.